# how to hide navigation controller number 1 instead navigation controller number 2 inside navigation controller number 1

Tags: ios, objective-c

[2 Controllers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FOSX4.png)
[PageviewController](https://i.stack.imgur.com/utJZy.png)

1)

```objc
- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(UIApplication *)application

[self.window  setRootViewController:navigationController];
```

2. On bottom toolbar button click in view pushing second `UINavigationController`:

```objc
[self.navigationController pushViewController:cnController animated:YES];
```

3. Loading of `UIPageViewController` in `UINNavigationController`:

```objc
@interface SwipeBetweenViewControllers : UINavigationController <UIPageViewControllerDelegate,UIPageViewControllerDataSource,UIScrollViewDelegate>
```

4. On bottom toolbar button click in view:

```objc
SampleViewController *viewController = [[SampleViewController alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewStyleGrouped];
viewController.model = settingsModel;
viewController.navigationItem.title = @"Settings";
[viewController willMoveToParentViewController:self];
// [[self navigationController] setNavigationBarHidden:YES animated:YES];
[self.view addSubview:viewController.view];
[self addChildViewController: viewController];
[viewController didMoveToParentViewController:self];

[self.navigationController pushViewController:viewController animated:YES];
```

5. It shows 2 navigation controllers. I need to hide the top one when I issue following:

```objc
[[self navigationController] setNavigationBarHidden:YES animated:YES];
```

It hides `UIPageviewcontroller` navigation  and go back to original view. I also tried:

```objc
NSMutableArray *allControllers = [self.navigationController.viewControllers mutableCopy];
[allControllers removeObjectAtIndex:allControllers.count -1];
```

and also

```objc
for (UIViewController *controller in self.navigationController.viewControllers)
    {
        if ([controller isKindOfClass:[SampleViewController class]])
        {
        [[self navigationController] setNavigationBarHidden:YES animated:YES];
        }
}
```

How to hide specific original navigation controller?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all your help.
I was able to solve this.
Actually, I was pushing viewController to top one #1 navigationcontroller, whereas it was to pushed into bottom one #2 navigationcontroller.
And wrapping #2 navigationcontroller in a containerUIviewcontroller set right navigation.
Thanks